# SSIS deployment using DeploymentFileCompilerTask

Tags: deployment, ssis

I've read a lot around TFS deployment of SSIS packages - I have a VS2012 SSIS project and have created a .proj file using "DeploymentFileCompilerTask" to build the project into a .ispac:-

```
<UsingTask TaskName="DeploymentFileCompilerTask" AssemblyFile="..\tools\IntegrationServices.Build\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Build.dll" />
...
<DeploymentFileCompilerTask
  InputProject="$(SSISProjPath)"
  Configuration="Release"
  RootOutputDirectory="$(OutDir)"
  ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive">
```

i.e. the technique as outlined :-

https://gist.github.com/kulmam92/6433329

However the build is failing with :-

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

The question I have is what is the minimum I need on the server that executes the above.  I have read SSDT and/or SSIS needs to be deployed - there is also a technique relating to recompiling a Codeplex project (as outlined in http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/09/14/ssis-msbuild-task-now-included-in-msbuild-extension-pack.aspx) or combining particular components of SQL Server (http://www.networksteve.com/enterprise/topic.php/SSIS_Package_Deployment_to_Server_only_running_SSIS_(and_not_SQL/?TopicId=29646&Posts=2).

I don't really want to get too granular, I just wanted a definitive answer to a fairly common problem - can anyone assist.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has the same problem, the issue was 32-bit Vs 64-bit related - not the fact that the deployment was lacking a binary (in the GAC, etc)

Within the Build Definition (default build.xml file) go to Process | Advance | MSBuild Platform | Change from 'Auto' to 'X86'